# How do I combind two git projects (git twitter4) and (git accumulo) to build a project that uses both?

Tags: java, git, maven, twitter4j, accumulo

I am doing twitter analysis in java (making the switch) and putting results in accumulo.

I found the git twitter4 project and there is the accumulo project.

I am new at maven and git.

I want to know how to:
1) Combine the projects without an IDE
2) Combine the projects with netbeans

thanks for your assistance!

Chris

Comment: Since you use maven, why not add these two projects as dependencies in your pom.xml? Oh, and while we're at it, try gradle instead of maven

Comment: +1 on the Gradle thought!

Comment: I am a simple math guy and am new to maven. I am trying to use the twitter4 api to get stuff and accumulo to store it. I appreciate your quick response and welcome some more in depth dialogue as I am just starting this and you both have a wealth of experience please get back to me!

Comment: I don't event have a pom.xml except for hello world at this point to convey my naivety.